# CAML IN operator and AND operator with multiple condition

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, caml

The Following CAML Query Not Working for me.. I am not aware much about sharepoint platform. i am using SP 2007 and trying to use IN operator for a lookup field.

```
"<Where>"
                                + "<And>"
                                + "<And>"
                                + "<In>"
                                + "<FieldRef Name='Role'/>"
                                + "<Values>"
                                + "<Value Type = 'Text'>A</Value>"
                                + "<Value Type = 'Text'>B</Value>"
                                + "</Values>"
                                + "</In>"
                                + "<Leq>"
                                + "<FieldRef Name='Enddate'/><Value Type = 'DateTime'>" + SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(Dt) + " </Value>"
                                + "</Leq>"
                                + "</And>"
                                + "<Includes>"
                                + "<FieldRef Name='Menu'/><Value Type='Text'>Benefits</Value>"
                                + "</Includes>"
                                + "</And>"
                                + "</Where>";
```

The above query not return anything but i have values in my list for the above combination.

If I slightly modify the query like following w/o using IN then it is working fine.

```
"<Where>"
                                + "<And>"
                                + "<And>"
                                + "<Eq>"
                                + "<FieldRef Name='Role'/>"
                                //+ "<Values>"
                                + "<Value Type = 'Text'>A</Value>"
                                //+ "<Value Type = 'Text'>B</Value>"
                                //+ "</Values>"
                                + "</Eq>"
                                + "<Leq>"
                                + "<FieldRef Name='Enddate'/><Value Type = 'DateTime'>" + SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(Dt) + " </Value>"
                                + "</Leq>"
                                + "</And>"
                                + "<Includes>"
                                + "<FieldRef Name='Menu'/><Value Type='Text'>Benefits</Value>"
                                + "</Includes>"
                                + "</And>"
                                + "</Where>";
```

(Please Don't Suggest me to use CAML Query builder cuz I cannot install anything on my DEV box. And Moreover I haven't install SP WSS in my local :) )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The IN operator for CAML was introduced in Sharepoint 2010. You cannot use it in Sharepoint 2007. To achieve the same result you will have to write it as a OR's instead.

```
<Or>
 <Eq>
  <FieldRef Name='Role' />
  <Value Type='Text'>A</Value>
 </Eq>
 <Eq>
  <FieldRef Name='Role' />
  <Value Type='Text'>B</Value>
 </Eq>
</Or>
```

Comment: Thanks Onots...I came across the following link and He also stated the same like you :)http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/64e329f1-9f11-4c80-a2c3-3062435c442a

Answer (score 2):

If Someone still Use Sharepoint 2007 and want to use IN operator with multiple Conditions, You can achieve this like following,Here I used "OR" operator instead "IN"

```
string lCAMLQuery =                "<Where>"
                                        + "<And>"
                                        + "<And>"
                                            + "<Leq>"
                                                + "<FieldRef Name='Enddate'/><Value Type = 'DateTime'>" + SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(Dt) + " </Value>"
                                            + "</Leq>"
                                        + "<Or>"
                                            + "<Eq>"
                                                + "<FieldRef Name='Role' />"
                                                + "<Value Type='Text'>A</Value>"
                                            + "</Eq>"
                                             + "<Eq>"
                                                + "<FieldRef Name='Role' />"
                                                + "<Value Type='Text'>D</Value>"
                                            + "</Eq>"
                                        + "</Or>"
                                        + "</And>"
                                            + "<Includes>"
                                                + "<FieldRef Name='Menu'/><Value Type='Text'>Benefits</Value>"
                                            + "</Includes>"
                                        + "</And>"
                                    + "</Where>";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string lCAMLQuery = @"<Where>
                    <And>
                    <And>
                        <Leq>
                            <FieldRef Name='Enddate'/><Value Type = 'DateTime'>" + SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(Dt) + " </Value>
                        </Leq>
                    <Or>
                        <Eq>
                            <FieldRef Name='Role' />
                            <Value Type='Text'>A</Value>
                        </Eq>
                        <Eq>
                            <FieldRef Name='Role' />
                            <Value Type='Text'>D</Value>
                        </Eq>
                    </Or>
                    </And>
                        <Includes>
                            <FieldRef Name='Menu'/><Value Type='Text'>Benefits</Value>
                        </Includes>
                    </And>";
```